# Is it possible to make HD / SSD with Windows 10 from an old PC bootable on USB?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd, liveusb

The motherboard of my laptop died, so I decided to buy a case for the SSD I had in that laptop.

That SSD has Windows 10 in it. I have opened it on another PC to retrieve my important files so now I'm free to format it and use it as a glorified pendrive until I buy a new laptop and install it in that

But

Before I do that though, I was wondering if it would be possible to tweak it to boot this Windows through USB

If I just try to boot from USB, I just get a message saying there isn't anything to boot there ("No boot device found. Press any key to reboot" or something on these lines)

Comment: OEM licenses cannot be transferred, it’s not possible to boot a Windows installation, from a machine that’s significantly different.  There are third part tools, that can be used, to create and restore an image that allows that (but your license couldn’t be used). Your better off just manually transferring the files yourself

Comment: Thanks, Ramhound. I'm having to use a borrowed laptop from my company to continue working, so my plan was to use the Windows in that SSD for personal stuff. I really find it infuriating that Windows licenses are stuck to specific machines even though it is just software... If that wasn't the case, I could just buy a laptop with Linux in it and stick this SSD into it.

Comment: Retail Windows licenses do not have the same restriction.

Comment: hm... I wonder how expensive that could be and how feasible it would be to self-build a laptop... Anyway, thanks for the insights

Comment: Uneconomical you would be better off just purchasing a retail license.  The costs of an OEM Windows license is built-into the price of the device, but it's heavily discounted, due to the fact the license cannot be moved to another device.